# How to do responsive scroll event with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive scrollY event using JS.
I would like to animate a div on mobile and desktop.
The problem is that on mobile, the animation appear at scrollY 2000 and on desktop scrollY 2800.

How can I animate it on desktop devices ?

There is the code I would like to use but it's not working:

```
if( window.scrollY > 2000 || window.scrollY > 2800){
    percentDev.style.animation = "percentBareDev 2s forwards";
    percentTeam.style.animation = "percentBareTeam 2s 
    forwards";
    percentRewards.style.animation = "percentBareRewards  2s 
    forwards";
}
```

Comment: You should decide first how to identify a mobile device in JS, so your condition could be something like `if( (window.scrollY > 2000 && isMobile) || (window.scrollY > 2800 && !isMobile) )`

Comment: Consider using viewport sizes instead of pixel values

Comment: If those magic numbers resulted from an attempt to trigger this when a specific element is entering the viewport (or _has_ entered it for a specific amount), then your keyword is [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).